# Zuul api-gateway does not work with context root

Tags: netflix-zuul, http-status-code-405, contextroot

I am using zuul api gateway.

```
org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul
2.2.1.RELEASE
```

This call with this path works fine:

```
http://PMCS-HOMI:8085/spatest/service-synchronization/service/message
path: /spatest/service-synchronization/**
url: ${spa.synchronization.url}/service-synchronization
```

This call with this path does not work. I get an http error 405.

```
http://PMCS-HOMI:8085/spa/service-synchronization/service/message
path: /spa/service-synchronization/**
url: ${spa.synchronization.url}/service-synchronization
```

**/spa is too the context root of my application.**

I will be very grateful if someone helps me.

Regards.